# How to map list and implement async within it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, asynchronous

```
renderDuration(x) {
  return 'abc'
}

render() {
  return (
    <View>
      {this.props.list.map(x => (
        <Text>{this.renderDuration(x)}</Text>
      ))}
    </View>
  )
}
```

The above code is working perfectly fine. The situation is very basic which is looping the list and for each of the element, call the method `renderDuration` and get the individual string value. Now take a look below.

```
async renderDuration(x) {
  let someAsyncOpt = await getTextFromSomewhere();
  return someAsyncOpt;
}
```

So once the same method we change it to async method, it breaks and hitting exception

> Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_40, _65, _55, _72}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

I understand that a viable option is to get whatever data that's needed first, instead while render. This question is basically trying to explore the possibility to perform async operation while mapping, if it make sense?

**UPDATES:**

I've included the below code to show that it has nothing to do with wrong type of returning from async opt. It's basically the moment we include the keyword `async`, it will break

```
async renderDuration(x) {
  return 'abc';
}
```

Comment: Whats the response of this function await getTextFromSomewhere();? Looks like it returns an array or object and you are rendering it directly as an array or object. That’s the problem. Please share this getTextFromSomewhere(); code and the response of this function

Comment: @HemadriDasari: No that's not the problem. You can have a look at my updates

Comment: async and await should be implemented together. When there is no await there is no point in declaring function as async. So in sample case change async renderDuration(x) {
  return 'abc';
} to  renderDuration(x) {
  return 'abc';
} will work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**(Update) try to use this:**

```js
class Alpha{

// ...

// Update :
async renderDuration(x) {
   let someAsyncOpt = await Promise.all(getTextFromSomewhere());
   return someAsyncOpt;
}

render() {
  return (
    
     // Old :
      <View>
        {this.props.list.map(x => (
          <Text>{this.renderDuration(x)}</Text>
        ))}
      </View>
    
     // Update :
     <View>
      {
        this.props.list.map( 
            async (x) => { await this.renderDuration(x) } 
        );
      }
     </View>

    
  )
}

}
```

Comment: ahh yes `Promise.all`. Thanks!

Comment: `renderDuration` would have to be async to use `await`.

Comment: Also this async (x) => { this.renderDuration(x) }  should be async (x) => { await this.renderDuration(x) }